# AngularJS V1.2 - Error: $q is not a function

Tags: angularjs, q

```
(function () {
angular.module('Testing')
    .controller('Testing', Testing);
    Testing.$inject('$q', '$location', 'authentication');
    function  Testing($q, $location, authentication) {
    var vm = this;

    function asyncGreet(name) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(username){
                resolve('Hello, ' + username);
            }
            else {
                reject('Greeting ' +  name + 'is not allowed');
            }
        }, 3000)
    });
}

var promise = asyncGreet("oo");
promise.then(function (greeting) {
    console.log('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
});

} ());
```

I am using angular version 1.2.9, and i am trying to make use of $q, and i keep getting an error that says $q is not a function, .

Can someone please point me to what i am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Testing.$inject is an array, not a method call.

Comment: Hey @phix, don't know how i missed that, but i changed it, and it still gave the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q` !== `Promise` in your version.  I don't know when $q was changed to be a function, but I'm pretty sure much after 1.2.9. Any reason you're using such an old version?

Try this variation:

```js
var deferred = $q.defer();
setTimeout(function(){
  if(username){
    deferred.resolve()
  } else {
    deferred.reject()
  }
});
return deferred;
```

See docs for your version (at least, pre 1.3)

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.32/docs/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @georgeawg I used an earlier version later on yesterday and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Phix I was following a Tutorial online and they were using this version of Angular, as i just started learning and decided to stick to that. I used an earlier version and everything works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using angular version 1.2.9, and i am trying to make use of `$q`, and i keep getting an error that says `$q` is not a function, .

The error occurs because the ES6 style of making a promise with `$q` was introduced in AngularJS V1.3. For more information, see [Github commit - feat($q): add streamlined ES6-style interface for using $q.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f3a763fd2edd8a37b80c79a5aaa1444460cd2df7)

Instead of manufacturing a promise with `$q`, I recommend using the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout):

```
function asyncGreet(name) {
    ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶$̶q̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶,̶ ̶r̶e̶j̶e̶c̶t̶)̶ ̶{̶
        ̶s̶e̶t̶T̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶{̶
    return $timeout(function () {
        if(username){
            return ('Hello, ' + username);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject('Greeting ' +  name + 'is not allowed');
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) is AngularJS's wrapper for [window.setTimeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler). The fn function is wrapped into a try/catch block and delegates any exceptions to [`$exceptionHandler` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler).

The return value of calling `$timeout` is a promise, which will be resolved when the delay has passed and the timeout function, if provided, is executed.

For more information, see [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Answer (score 0):

there's an error in the injection as suggested in the comments

```
Testing.$inject('$q', '$location', 'authentication')
```

should be

```
Testing.$inject = ['$q', '$location', 'authentication']
```

link to [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation)

Comment: Hello @karim, Thank you, I don't know how i missed that, although i still changed it and got the same error as before.